# Ms Access, group by specific date

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to group by specific date in ms access? I would like to create a monthly report which will bring me the expenses/income from my database. However, I want this report to group the results NOT BY YEAR (1/1-31/12) but from 1/9-31/8 (my business year is from September-August). Is it possible to group the results the way I want?

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to group all income/expense per fiscal year (or business year) where the fiscal year starts on September 1st.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to group by fiscal year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Select
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, YourDateField), "yyyymm") As FiscalYearMonth,
    <other fields>
From
    YourTable
Group By
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, YourDateField), "yyyymm")
```

For your specific table, it could be something like:

```
Select 
    Description, 
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, [YourDateField]), "yyyymm") As FiscalYearMonth,
    Sum([Sum]) AS [Sum]
From 
    [MyTable]
Where
    [MyTable].Category = "Misc"
Group By
    [MyTable].Description,
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, YourDateField), "yyyymm")
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly I should insert this code? My access SQL looks like:<br/>Select [MyTable].Description, Sum([My.Table].Sum) AS Sum<br>FROM [MyTable]<br/>WHERE (([MyTable].Category)="Misc"))<br/>GROUP BY [MyTable].Description;

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great!